# Idiomatic way to get foreign key from a table

Tags: elixir, ecto

Lets assume I have a table `"customers"`. And I want to get the foreign key of that table.

We can get the table name from model by using `model`.__struct.__meta`

We can also get model name from table by loading all the modules and get the model pattern match with  table name

Is this possible that we get a foreign key from a table?

What will be the best approach to do this?

And if its possible in ecto?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a foreign key"? Can you give an example of a model and the expected output?

Comment: for example in my `customer` model if i have a foreign key `inserted_by` and i want to get the `inserted_by` foreign key name . how can i do this? the output will be the name of the `foreign_key`

Comment: What happens if you have multiple foreign keys on a record?

Comment: Justin Wood  thats what i am asking that if its possible to get the foreign keys single or multiple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can find the foreign key of every `belongs_to` association in a model:

```
schema "comments" do
  belongs_to :post, MyApp.Post
  belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
end
```

```
alias MyApp.Comment

for name <- Comment.__schema__(:associations),
    %Ecto.Association.BelongsTo{owner_key: owner_key} <- [Comment.__schema__(:association, name)] do
  IO.inspect owner_key
end
```

Output:

```
:post_id
:user_id
```

`owner_key` is the column name in the current table. There's also `related_key` available which is the column name in the related table.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: If there are multiple foreign keys in a model. In the above loop is there a way i can filter based on the model they are related to. so i get only that specific key

Comment: Change `%Ecto.Association.BelongsTo{owner_key: owner_key}` to `x` and then do `IO.inspect(x)` in the for body. You'll see all information available in that struct including module names.

Comment: Thanks that's what i need.